# How to make UIView move by click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, interface-builder

I'm not sure whether I can describe it properly. It's a kind of UIView, and we see only it's part  (with arrow,maybe. on the bottom of screen,maybe). User can click on it, and this view appears fullscreen(usually developer leaves there some additional information). How can I make it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just put the logic that just setting of view Y coordinate of That View and when user click on Button. that et animation and at the re setting the view frame with Y coordinate setting like:

```
 yourview.frame = CGRectMake(0,280,320,568);

  [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                              delay:0.1
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                         animations:^{

                            yourview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);  
                    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                   }];
```

Also see this example:

https://github.com/crocodella/PullableView

Here above github demo this same that you are looking for its output like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
-(void)show
{
    [viewObj setFrame:CGRectMake(viewObj.frame.origin.x,viewObj.frame.origin.y,viewObj.frame.size.width, viewObj.frame.size.height)];//Here "viewObj.frame.origin.y" means 568
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
     {
         [viewObj setFrame:CGRectMake(viewObj.frame.origin.x,0,viewObj.frame.size.width, viewObj.frame.size.height)];
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
     }];
}

-(void)hide
{
    [viewObj setFrame:CGRectMake(viewObj.frame.origin.x,viewObj.frame.origin.y,viewObj.frame.size.width, viewObj.frame.size.height)];//Here "viewObj.frame.origin.y" means 0
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
     {
         [viewObj setFrame:CGRectMake(viewObj.frame.origin.x,568,viewObj.frame.size.width, viewObj.frame.size.height)];
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at UIView reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Specifically:

```
@property(nonatomic) CGPoint center
```

And

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations
```

Example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        myView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y + myOffset);
    }];
```

Duration is in seconds. In this case, 2 seconds.

If you're using `AutoLayout`, you probably want to change the `layout constant`, rather then `center` property.

About Layout Constrains:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html

Look at `constant` property. You can also drag a constrain  outlet from Interface Builder and access its `constant`. It's really simple once you get to know it a bit.